# Metalsmith.js: How to build to same directory as build script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, metalsmith

I am completely new to metalsmith. I've been following this tutorial: http://www.robinthrift.com/post/metalsmith-part-1-setting-up-the-forge/

I want to build my site to the root directory of my project (the same dir as the build script). I want to do this because I want github pages to play nicely with it. But when I try to build, I get this error: Error: EBUSY, resource busy or locked

Here is my dir structure:

- project_folder/

  - _site-src/

    - index.html
  - node_modules
  - build.js
  - package.json

Here is my build.js source:

```
var Metalsmith = require("metalsmith");

Metalsmith(__dirname)
    .source("_site_src")
    .destination(".")
    .build();
```

What I want my project dir to look like:

- project_folder/

  - _site-src/

    - index.html
  - node_modules
  - build.js
  - package.json
  - index.html

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm not at a machine where I can test this but I would guess that you're trying to overwrite the files that you're reading from. Try changing it to `.destination("\..")`?

Comment: Besides needing a double \ to do what I think you mean, it didn't work. I tried "\..", "\\..", "..", ".", "/..", "/." and all of them failed. I just ended up using a grunt build script that copies files out of a build dir into the current dir, however I don't consider that an answer to this question because that's just ridiculous.

Comment: I agree that its not a solution. I'd say workaround. Have you tried turning the default option `clean` to false?

Comment: James - That was it. That solved it! How did you figure that out? I feel like that should be in plain sight in some documentation somewhere. If you make that into an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: It was pure speculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message:

> Error: EBUSY, resource busy or locked

seems to be a file locked/in use error. (I'm not that familiar with Node.js errors)

I would assume this is happening when Metalsmith tries to clean the build folder (which is your solution folder i.e. a really bad idea). This is on by default but it can be turned off.

To turn this off use:

```
.clean(false)
```

before you build.

---

**BUT** if you remove items from your source folder they won't be removed from your build folder. You might be able to handle this by a custom clean-up script or plugin.

I'm not experienced with github pages but I think there should be a better alternative to the avoid the problem.

You could possibly add a symbolic link to the build folder from the project folder for the `index.html` file.

Comment: You can use `git subtree` to get github pages to serve a sub-directory up as the root. If your build directory is called 'build' then: `git subtree push --prefix build origin gh-pages`

Comment: Git has nothing to do with this question or answer.

Comment: Yes it does. The question was asked because he wants "github pages to play nicely with it". You answered: "I'm not experienced with github pages but I think there should be a better alternative to the avoid the problem". And I'm saying the better alternative to avoid the problem is to get Github Pages to serve out a specific subdirectory.

Comment: @poshaughnessy Ah I see that now. Still if you think that's an answer then post it. Your comment makes no sense attached to this answer as its addressing the metalsmith.js side of things.